# Error in reading data into 3x3 matrix in Fortran

Tags: io, fortran

I am having difficulties reading in a line of data into 3x3 matrix in Fortran.

Basically, I write a text file from which I have written a 3x3 variable 'VAR' using

```
   open(unit = 1, file = 'Testfile', form = 'formatted', access = 'sequential', status = 'unknown', position='append')
      write(1,'(9ES15.8E2)') VAR(:,:,n)
```

When I do this, the text file contains 9 elements (3x3) in a row in column-dominant order (i.e. a row exhibits (1,1), (2,1), (3,1) ... (3,3)) element in order on each n-th row.

I'm copying and pasting the input text file here. So this is how the file is written.

```
 11.19700702E+31 12.52286128E+29 13.00849485E+31 140.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 00
 21.00000000E+00 22.00000000E+00 23.00000000E+00 24.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00-7.72501181E+29 2.89893158E+29 6.10314111E+30
 31.00000000E+00 32.00000000E+00 33.00000000E+00 34.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00-1.11738378E+31 2.00291396E+31 4.38402635E+31
 41.00000000E+00 42.00000000E+00 43.00000000E+00 44.400000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00-1.19700702E+31-7.52286128E+29 2.00849485E+31
 51.00000000E+00 52.00000000E+00 530.00000000E+00 54.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00-7.72501181E+29 2.89893158E+29 6.10314111E+30
 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00-1.11738378E+31 2.00291396E+31 4.38402635E+31
 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00-1.19700702E+31-7.52286128E+29 2.00849485E+31
 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00-7.72501181E+29 2.89893158E+29 6.10314111E+30
 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00 0.00000000E+00-1.11738378E+31 2.00291396E+31 4.38402635E+31
```

Then I try to read this data from another program by writing

```
 open(unit = 1, file = 'Testfile', &
 & form = 'formatted', access = 'sequential', status = 'old')

 do n = 1, m
   read(1,'(9ES15.8E2)') ((VAR(i,j,n), j=1,3), i=1,3)
enddo
```

the code does not read in the elements as I want it to. It reads in like the following (and also runs into an error after the first loop) that I can't figure out what kind of order it is reading the values in.

```
 VAR   1.11970071E+32   140.000000       0.00000000       1.25228614E+30   0.00000000       0.00000000       1.30084944E+32   0.00000000       0.00000000    

        At line 309 of file SL_MODEL.f90 (unit = 1, file = '../OUTPUT_FW_NoTPW/Testfile')

    Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 6 of list input
```

I also tried using

```
read(1,*) ((VAR(i,j,n), j=1,3), i=1,3)
```

, which only gives me a runtime error (End of file).

Does anybody have any insight into this problem?

Comment: Please show an example of the input file and the output (and how you get that output) which has the "random" parts.

Comment: @Nisarg Why did you make such a strange edit?

Comment: @gksrufp Please try to format your questions so that they are better readable.

Comment: just edited and provided more info, is it better?

Comment: See my edits. Anyway, it is likely a duplicate. You need to repeat your format. Try `'(9(9ES15.8E2))'` or `'(99999(9ES15.8E2))'` or `'(*(9ES15.8E2))'`

Comment: Or you  could even just use `read(1,*) ((VAR(i,j,n), j=1,3), i=1,3)`, you say it gives you the end of file, but check that the nnumber of lines is correct first.

Comment: @VladimirF As I have edited first but my edits has not been approved while some else edited too at the same time. It got overwritten by my edits later. it's seems weird.

Comment: @VladimirF, Nisarg's edit was probably started before I submitted and submitted after.

Comment: @Vladimir I think the problem has to do with the format - because I just tested with another textfile with integer values, and the code worked perfectly.. '(9(9ES15.8E2))' and others don't work..

Comment: @VladimirF Also, what do you mean it's a duplicate? Thank you!

Comment: @francescalus yeah you are right and to be honest.. I did not get any notifications while your edits submitted. otherwise, I should be submit new edits.

Comment: @Nisarg, it could even have been the other way around: I could have submitted my edit after you submitted yours (while it was still pending approval, which mine didn't need).  The crucial thing is, we both started editing from the same point.  This is a known issue in editing.

Comment: problem SOLVED.

Comment: It was the space between the values - there was no space between some values (e.g. 6th to 7th elements of the second line of the Testfile) and the program thought the numbers are just one value..

Comment: Thank you everyone for looking at the problem!!